# Mail merging with JACOB

Tags: java, com, ms-word, jacob

I'm developing a CRM in Java and I need to mail merge my contacts into a template file, so I searched a bit around how to do it and the only satisfying answer was to use COM via JACOB

But I prefer to ask experienced people on it before starting to learn COM, which seem to be an old tech.

Is there a "better"* solution that Java+JACOB+COM to mail merge MSWord (Doc and Docx) documents with Java ?

*I think that's pretty subjective :/

EDIT : I'm limited to free solutions

Comment: I maintain a poweful docx templating engine, running on nodejs. It has a cli, but works only for docx. Check it out: https://github.com/edi9999/docxtemplater

Comment: I hope you're not planning to use Word on the server.  It's not designed to do that.

Comment: You could try apache poi

Comment: You could use docx4j's https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/samples/docx4j/org/docx4j/samples/FieldsMailMerge.java on docx files; if you want to process legacy binary doc files, convert them to docx first.